# plupload jquery plugin - corrupted file after upload

Tags: jquery, plugins, upload, plupload

I'm using Plupload to upload files into one server, the upload process works well but when i opened the file (ex: docx) it says it's corrupted and has additional data in it (i think it is  some header from the xmlhttprequest).

You can see the additional data in this link -> http://prntscr.com/4hl5lo

My code:

Client Side:

```
AJS.$("input#edit-template-file").replaceWith('<div id="container"> <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a> <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a> </div>');

    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',

        browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
        container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself

        url : '[my url]',
        multi_selection: false, 
        send_file_name: false,
        chunk_size: 0,
        filters : {
            max_file_size : '100mb',
            mime_types: [
                {title : "Doc files", extensions : "docx,docm,dotx,dotm,odt,rtf"}
            ]
        },

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : 'Moxie.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : 'Moxie.xap',


        init: {
            PostInit: function() {
                document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                    uploader.start();
                    return false;
                };
            },
            BeforeUpload: function(up, file) {
                // Called right before the upload for a given file starts, can be used to cancel it if required
                delete up.settings.multipart_params; //i have tried this to remove the additional data written in the file but without sucess
                console.log('[BeforeUpload]', 'File: ', file);
            },
            UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
                AJS.progressBars.update("#templateBar", file.percent);
            },
            FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
                console.log(info.response);
                if (info.response != '') {
                    AJS.$(fileFieldId).val(info.response);
                    AJS.$("div#container").attr( 'name', file.name );
                    setSubmitState(false);
                }
            },

            Error: function(up, err) {
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
            }
        }
    });

    uploader.init();
```

Server side (java) :

```
  public Response createFile(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    final String templatesPath = buildTemplatesPath();
    final File templatesDir = new File(templatesPath);
    if (!templatesDir.exists()) {
        templatesDir.mkdir();
    }
    final String tmpPath = buildTMPPath();
    final File tmpDir = new File(tmpPath);
    if (!tmpDir.exists()) {
        tmpDir.mkdir();
    }

    final String fileId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    try {
        writeToFile(is, buildFilePath(fileId));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unable to write template", e);
        return Response.status(500);
    }

    return Response.status(200);

}

  private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) throws Exception {

    try {
        final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unable write file", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I've been researching on the subject and found the file where Plupload is writing the additional header in the xmlhttprequest ( https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/blob/master/src/flash/src/com/XMLHttpRequest.as ), but i cant remove that data, any help ?

Answer (score -2):

No nothing is corrupted but you have to refreshing a all href scipt and css script that are added in img_upload.php

I mean which css file and jquery file include their path are replace  by downloading jquery and css file otherwise check the plugin by replaces jquery and css by their online path where the file store then after check the plugin

Comment: Sorry Ankit i did not understand what you're trying to explain. The file after be uploaded is corrupted, as you can see in this link http://prntscr.com/4hlkj6 .